# Page is loading without rendering style.css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

Here is my project directory where I have

> style.css

under Content and

> image.jpg

under Images

[image]

> Login.aspx page is default page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="LoginDemo.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />

    <title>LOGIN</title>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is CSS

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body{
    background-image:url(Images/image.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:Times New Roman ;
}
```

Page is loaded successfully but without loading background image. Please help me. I read different article and as per suggested solutions I do the same steps but still there is problem.

Comment: Have you try to clear cache or use with a fresh browser?

Comment: Why the `runat="server"`? usually that attribute implies some server side execution/processing and in the stylesheet it looks unnecesary (problematic since there is no handler configured in IIS for css extension).

Comment: @Sigma yes I clear the cache and use fresh browser. bradbury9 I read 1 article and there they suggest to use runat=server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images is not in the Content folder. so in your css, you should go back a folder:

```
  background-image:url(../Images/image.jpg);
```

Note the `../` before Images folder in the path

Comment: thanks dear now I understand. But 1 question why its not working when I use url(~/Images/image.jgp)

Comment: @SalmanMushtaq you are welcome. I'm not sure but i think ~/ has meaning in Asp.net and not css

Answer (score 2):

put a single quote before and after your image path,and also use (..) to refer up directory, so correct your css code with these lines:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body{
    background-image:url('../Images/image.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:Times New Roman ;
}
```

and where is your webpage location ? is it in a directory ?

Comment: Thanks. But still I am confused why its not work when I used url(~/Images/image.jpg), Web pages located under project directory

Comment: @SalmanMushtaq your welcome Salman, i think css doesn't understand (~) character and also css files are located in a sub-directory which you should go up directory then addressing your own folder that image located.

Answer (score 0):

Create an error in style.css file, compiler didn't listening the file. clean the solution and Rebuilt it again. Surely It will work.